# Strange JSON Splice Formatting Issue (Some Keys are Not Being Outputted as Strings)

Tags: javascript, json

So I need to split this large JSON file into smaller pieces, when I execute the code posted below it works (kind of). The format of the output is very weird as you can see in the image not all of the keys are strings. Does anyone know why this occurs?

(The JSON file that I am using is very long, I have shortened it for the demo)

```
const data = {
"labels": [
{
            "Part Name*": "10000",
            "Control Number": "10000",
            "Maintenance Category": "SWITCH",
            "Description": "IEC Load Switch, Open - Front / Door, OFF-ON 90°, 16A, 6 Poles",
            "Manufacturer": "Allen Bradley",
            "Model": "194E-E16-1753 C",
            "OEM Part Number": "4008497340",
            "Initial Cost": " $52.23 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $52.23 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "OMNICAL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10001",
            "Control Number": "10001",
            "Maintenance Category": "CONTACTOR",
            "Description": "100-C IEC Contactor, 24V DC Electronic Coil, Screw Terminals, Line Side, 16A, 0 N.O. 1 N.C. Auxiliary Contact Configuration, Single Pack",
            "Manufacturer": "Allen Bradley",
            "Model": "100-C16EJ10 B",
            "OEM Part Number": "100-C16EJ10 B",
            "Initial Cost": " $102.28 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $102.28 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "OMNICAL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10002",
            "Control Number": "10002",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "PhotoEYE Controller Photoelectric amplifier ",
            "Manufacturer": "Telco",
            "Model": "PA 11 A 303 T",
            "OEM Part Number": "453190300",
            "Initial Cost": " $211.16 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $211.16 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "SHOPCROSS"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10003",
            "Control Number": "10003",
            "Maintenance Category": "SPRING",
            "Description": "Spring for scisor lift truck.",
            "Manufacturer": "ULINE",
            "Model": "H-1785-P10",
            "OEM Part Number": "P10",
            "Initial Cost": " $6.60 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $6.60 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "ULINE"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10004",
            "Control Number": "10004",
            "Maintenance Category": "SWITCH",
            "Description": "IEC Limit Switch, side rotary lever, 90 degree adjustable head. PG11 capable entry with 1/2in NPT adapter. ",
            "Manufacturer": "Automation Direct",
            "Model": "AAP2T41Z11",
            "OEM Part Number": "AAP2T41Z11",
            "Initial Cost": " $12.50 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $12.50 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "AUTOMATION DIRECT"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10005",
            "Control Number": "10005",
            "Maintenance Category": "RELAY",
            "Description": "Fulton Burner Relay",
            "Manufacturer": "Fulton Boiler Works ",
            "Model": "240000421",
            "OEM Part Number": "240000421",
            "Initial Cost": " $55.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $55.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "NRI INDUSTRIAL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10006",
            "Control Number": "10006",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "5/2 way valve, pnumatic valve, poppet valve (Clam)",
            "Manufacturer": "Waircom",
            "Model": "UKCA4/U",
            "OEM Part Number": "UKCA4/U",
            "Initial Cost": " $24.30 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $24.30 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "NRI INDUSTRIAL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10007",
            "Control Number": "10007",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "Pnuematic Solenoid (Clam)",
            "Manufacturer": "Waircom",
            "Model": "ULCSV/R1105-60",
            "OEM Part Number": "ULCSV/R1105-60",
            "Initial Cost": " $85.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $85.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "WAIRCOM"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10008",
            "Control Number": "10008",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "Electric Over Air Valve 12V DC",
            "Manufacturer": "MAC",
            "Model": "45A-AA2-DFBA-1BA",
            "OEM Part Number": "45AAA2DFBA1BA",
            "Initial Cost": " $72.70 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $72.70 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "MPPARTS"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10009",
            "Control Number": "10009",
            "Maintenance Category": "CONTACTOR",
            "Description": "Contact Block, 6 A, 120 V, 1 Pole, Screw",
            "Manufacturer": "Eaton Cutler Hammer",
            "Model": "HT8A",
            "OEM Part Number": "HT8A",
            "Initial Cost": " $25.49 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $25.49 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "NEWARK"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10010",
            "Control Number": "10010",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "Flow Control with Fitting",
            "Manufacturer": "SMC Pnuematics",
            "Model": "AS1201F-U10/32-07",
            "OEM Part Number": "AS1201F-U10/32-07",
            "Initial Cost": " $7.56 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $7.56 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "ALLIED ELECTRONICS"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10011",
            "Control Number": "10011",
            "Maintenance Category": "CLAMP",
            "Description": "Superfix Cushioned Pipe Clamp, Electro Galvanized Steel",
            "Manufacturer": "nVent CADDY",
            "Model": "1RVC3",
            "OEM Part Number": "454006",
            "Initial Cost": " $3.11 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $3.11 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "GRAINGER"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10012",
            "Control Number": "10012",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "Flow Control with Fitting",
            "Manufacturer": "SMC Pnuematics",
            "Model": "KJ20732",
            "OEM Part Number": "KJ20732",
            "Initial Cost": " $12.70 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $12.70 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "ALLIED ELECTRONICS"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10013",
            "Control Number": "10013",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "White retroreflector, Rectangular 40.3x59.9mm 30 deg directional angle",
            "Manufacturer": "Omron",
            "Model": "E39-R1S",
            "OEM Part Number": "E39-R1S",
            "Initial Cost": " $25.72 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $25.72 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "NEWARK"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10014",
            "Control Number": "10014",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "White retroreflector, Square 100x100mm",
            "Manufacturer": "SICK",
            "Model": "PL100",
            "OEM Part Number": "5321625",
            "Initial Cost": " $32.24 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $32.24 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "CONTROL SOURCE INC."
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10015",
            "Control Number": "10015",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "White retroreflector, Rectangular 60x40.5mm",
            "Manufacturer": "Banner Engineering",
            "Model": "BLT-60x40c",
            "OEM Part Number": "44997",
            "Initial Cost": " $11.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $11.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "BANNER ENGINEERING"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10016",
            "Control Number": "10016",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "Black retroreflector, 51x61mm",
            "Manufacturer": "SICK",
            "Model": "P250",
            "OEM Part Number": "5304812",
            "Initial Cost": " $-   ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "SICK"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10017",
            "Control Number": "10017",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "White retroreflector, 48x48mm",
            "Manufacturer": "IFM",
            "Model": "E20722",
            "OEM Part Number": "E20722",
            "Initial Cost": " $16.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $16.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "IFM"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10018",
            "Control Number": "10018",
            "Maintenance Category": "PHOTOELECTRIC ",
            "Description": "Retroreflective laser sensor ",
            "Manufacturer": "IFM",
            "Model": "OJ5136",
            "OEM Part Number": "OJ5136",
            "Initial Cost": " $238.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $238.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "IFM"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10019",
            "Control Number": "10019",
            "Maintenance Category": "FAN BLADE",
            "Description": "Advanced Air Intl. 4 Blade, 1.9380 in dia, CCW Fan Blade",
            "Manufacturer": "Advanced Air International ",
            "Model": "F-1.9380CCW4-40",
            "OEM Part Number": "F-1.9380CCW4-40",
            "Initial Cost": " quote ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " quote ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "ADVANCED AIR"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10020",
            "Control Number": "10020",
            "Maintenance Category": "VALVE",
            "Description": "4 Way, 2 Position Single Solenoid ",
            "Manufacturer": "Parker",
            "Model": "PVLB1016067W2",
            "OEM Part Number": "PVLB1016067W2",
            "Initial Cost": " $117.18 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $117.18 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "HYDRADYNE"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10021",
            "Control Number": "10021",
            "Maintenance Category": "LUBRICATOR",
            "Description": "1/2\" NPT DynaFlo Standard Lubricator ",
            "Manufacturer": "DynaFlo",
            "Model": "L1391",
            "OEM Part Number": "27131064",
            "Initial Cost": " $105.70 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BOX",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $105.70 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "FASTENALL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10022",
            "Control Number": "10022",
            "Maintenance Category": "WASHER",
            "Description": "Nylon Washer 15mm",
            "Manufacturer": "3M",
            "Model": "78-8017-9074-8",
            "OEM Part Number": "18-40002-2503-5",
            "Initial Cost": " $4.71 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $4.71 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "FASTENALL"
        },
        {
            "Part Name*": "10023",
            "Control Number": "10023",
            "Maintenance Category": "WASHER ",
            "Description": "M10 Washer ",
            "Manufacturer": "3M",
            "Model": "26-1004-5510-9",
            "OEM Part Number": "26-1004-5510-9",
            "Initial Cost": " $4.00 ",
            "Criticality": "Low",
            "ABC Code (A, B, C, or nothing)": "C",
            "Order Unit": "BAG",
            "Order Unit Qty": "1",
            "Order Unit Cost ": " $4.00 ",
            "Reorder": "1",
            "Min": "1",
            "Max": "6",
            "Suppliers": "HILLAS"
        },
]
};
const dataRange = data.labels.splice(0,11);
console.log(dataRange)
```

Sample Output:
[image]

Comment: The logged output is just a javascript array, not JSON, so only the properties that have invalid characters in them (spaces in the case) have quotes. If you want to see it as JSON you'll need to stringify it. `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataRange, null, 2));`

Comment: You have a Javascript object, not a JSON.  quotes are only required in a JS Object if the key has special characters in it like spaces.   As `Control Number: '1000'` would be invalid otherwise.  But if you did `console.log(JSON.stringify(dataRange, null, '  '))`  You would get the JSON quoted, as all keys in JSON need to be quoted.

Comment: It seems to be a nodeJS console output and that's how it treats keys that don't need to be quoted. Browser console logs behave differently.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript the keys are only needed to be in quotes (`'` or `"`) when the key is not just one word. The reason why some of the keys are represented as strings is because they are split up into multiple words.